# How to reorder and visualize an array in Grasshopper and/or Python?

Tags: python, arrays, data-manipulation, grasshopper

I solve Chinese Postman Problem for 172 nodes (vertices) and 452 arcs (edges) network with two vehicles via mixed integer programming. The graph is non-traversable so that some arcs in the route are traversed more than once. So the solution output is two lists of two types of arcs for each vehicle: one type is to service and another type is to transit. Each arc is represented as a pair of two nodes.

The issue here is that the arcs in the solution output are not ordered in a way to represent a real route.

So my questions are:
A. How to process the output data In Grasshopper into a real route, meaning, to reorder the array (the list of arcs) in such a sequence where each arc’s first node is the second node of the previous arc in the array.

For instance array 
ab, cd, bf, de, fc, ea
reorder into
ab, bf, fc, cd, de, ea

B. Is there a way to visualize the properly reordered list of arcs in such a way that each arc appears as an arrow of a distinct color (depending on whether it is to service or to transit type of arc), given that each node has its unique XY coordinates.

Thanks in advance.